# Dreamweaver PHP array dereferencing

Tags: php, arrays, dreamweaver, dereference, php-5.4

I just installed PHP 5.4 and now that it supports array dereferencing I want to use that in my projects.
Problem is that I'm working with Dreamweaver (CS6) and it gives me a syntax error for using the array brackets after the function parantheses.

Is there any way to mess around with Dreamweaver's syntax support (or maybe just tuning the syntax highlighting in the configuration/CodeColoring directory may be enough)?

Comment: I think you'll have to update to the latest version of Dreamweaver...

Comment: Stop using dreamweaver and move onto a better IDE... Netbeans, Eclipse, and Sublime are much better, even VIM or Notepad++ would be better suited for development.

Comment: Dreamweaver is made for frontend technologies like HTML, CSS and JS, not for PHP. Use PHPStorm or Netbeans!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to download another Editor if you work with PHP. Some fine examples: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_editors

Dreamweaver is build to work for designers. PHP != Design ;)

Comment: +1 for the last part :). I use Coda, been using it for 3 years and it's served me well. There are a few good free ones out there, Sublime and Intelija spring to mind.

Comment: Hey all. Thanks for all the answers.
I know that Dreamweaver is for designers but at the moment I'm kinda maid-of-all-work (also known as: student) which means I do all the Frontend AND PHP stuff.
I'm quite used to it and haven't found an IDE with a better support for HTML and CSS (and I don't like Eclipse to be honest).
I liked phpDesigner in terms of PHP editing but I switched back to Dreamweaver since it does a better job at the interaction of all the stuff together.
So long story short and back to the question: you don't see any ways of tweaking the Dreamweaver syntax support?

Comment: My personal preferences go to Netbeans. Someone who has experience with CSS and HTML won't need the features that Dreamweaver has to offer, the other IDEs will support auto-complete which is more than enough imo. The PHP features that Eclipse or Netbeans for example have to offer, outweigh Dreamweaver a lot :>

Comment: Yeah it's not that difficult to outweigh Dreamweaver in PHP features. ^^
But I don't agree with the first one - I know my stuff with CSS and HTML and the autocomplete isn't there to explain me what I am allowed to write there but to make writing way faster - which Dreamweaver does perfectly well.