# Dreamweaver CS6 syntax errors in php 5.4

Tags: php, dreamweaver, php-5.4

I installed Laravel L5, and when I open the config/app.php file with DW CS6, it says that the file has syntax errors. I guess the PHP syntax is outdated, but I can't find an update for this.

[image]

Comment: Seems that it is not treating `[ ]` as array syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I see that... any known fixes?

Comment: Most likely not, there are far better IDE's than dreamweaver nowadays. You should look around as there are also some very good free ones.

Comment: I was thinking this lately... PhpStorm looks nice, but if you want to recommend something else you can write me on ignjatov@gravity.mk. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend PhpStorm 100%, been using it for a few years now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dreamweaver PHP array dereferencing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746654/dreamweaver-php-array-dereferencing)

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's the same problem with that question, it didn't occur to me to search like that... anyway, I'm facing the same difficulties with the guy that asked that question too, I work backend AND frontend codes, that's why I'm still with the DW CS6 :)